# Optimal generalized bisection method

Tags: algorithms, efficiency, numerical-algorithms, binary-search

Suppose I'm looking for a some unknown number $x$ in the interval $[a,b]$ under the following assumptions:

- $x$ is unique.
- Given any $t \in [a,b]$ I can check, at some fixed computational cost, whether $t>x$. Let's call this operation $C(t)$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be some small number. I'm interested in efficient algorithms to find an interval $I$, containing $x$, with length $<\epsilon$. The bisection method begins by using $C((a+b)/2), $ halving $[a,b]$, and repeating the process 
 over $\log_2 \left((b-a)/\epsilon \right)$ times. I was wondering if there are more efficient modifications to it, such as breaking the interval into 3 or 4 subintervals at each iteration. Any other efficient alternative is also welcome. Thank you!

P.S. One can assume that $x$ is distributed uniformly in $[a,b]$, and that this process needs to be done many times for different $x$s.

Comment: In which computational model? Which cost measure do you apply? Have you analysed ternary, ... search; what was the result?

Comment: @Raphael I'm not sure what a computational model is. Each call to $C$ costs a fixed amount (I focus on time alone). I've tried ternary search, and it seems that binary is more effective.

Answer (score 2):

Take any policy that you like. It will consist in a number of calls to $C$ during which you will reduce the size of the incertainty of the location of $x$.

Whatever rule you use, you can't beat dichotomy, because if you split in unequal subintervals, you can always end-up in the longest, which is longer than the half.

This also holds in the average sense. Assume a split in relative sizes $\alpha$ and $1-\alpha$, which will be performed with these probabilities. The expectation of the relative length after a division is $\alpha^2+(1-\alpha)^2\ge1/2$. The minimum is reached for $\alpha=1/2$.

---

You might only improve on this result when $x$ is not uniformly distributed and you have some information about this distribution, such as the histogram of frequencies. (In such a case, the optimal rule is probably to split in equiprobable subintervals.)

Comment: @D.W.: I deleted because I am unsure about the last part (equiprobable intervals). And if I can confirm this, I plan to rewrite completely.)

Answer (score 1):

No.  You can't do better than binary search.  Without knowing $x$, there are at least $(b-a)/\epsilon$ possible answers.  This means it will take at least $\log_2((b-a)/\epsilon)$ bits to encode the answer, on average.  Each time you invoke the "check whether $t>x$" operation, you learn one bit of information about the answer.  Therefore you need to invoke that operation at least $\log_2((b-a)/\epsilon)$ times, on average.